# Python Pandas - select multi-level index based on some condition on values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

```
Premise Description                       Victim Sex
7TH AND METRO CENTER (NOT LINE SPECIFIC)  F               21
                                          M               36
                                          X                1
ABANDONED BUILDING ABANDONED HOUSE        F               98
                                          M              158
                                                        ... 
WEBSITE                                   F               38
                                          M               30
YARD (RESIDENTIAL/BUSINESS)               F             5694
                                          M             7229
                                          X              158
Name: Victim Sex, Length: 889, dtype: int64
```

I grouped the dataframe using the following code and the result is as above:

```
data.groupby(["Premise Description","Victim Sex"])["Victim Sex"].count()
```

I need to find for each Premise Description, the Victim Sex that was more victimized?
I need output as:

```
Premise Description                       Victim Sex
7TH AND METRO CENTER (NOT LINE SPECIFIC)  M               36
ABANDONED BUILDING ABANDONED HOUSE        M              158
....
```

Comment: can you provide text of the data frame (same as the image above)?

Comment: also, please clarify/specify *one* question.

Comment: @anon01 I have added the text for the image and make the question more clear with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
data.groupby(["Premise Description","Victim Sex"])["Victim Sex"].count().sort_values().groupby(level=0).tail(1)
```

---

**Sample df:**

```
    desp    Sex
0   a   m
1   a   m
2   b   f
3   a   f
4   b   m
5   c   f
6   b   m
7   c   f
8   c   m
9   b   f
10  a   f
11  b   m
12  c   f
```

---

```
u = df.groupby(["desp", "Sex"])["Sex"].count()
v = u.sort_values().groupby(level=0).tail(1)
```

---

**u:**

```
desp  Sex
a     f      2
      m      2
b     f      2
      m      3
c     f      3
      m      1
Name: Sex, dtype: int64
```

---

**v:**

```
desp  Sex
a     m      2
b     m      3
c     f      3
Name: Sex, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

So you initial dataframe may look like this:

`>>df`

```
   desp Sex
0   a   m
1   a   m
2   b   f
3   a   f
4   b   m
5   c   f
6   b   m
7   c   f
8   c   m
9   b   f
10  a   f
11  b   m
12  c   f
```

We grouped it to:

```
g=df.groupby(['desp','Sex'])['Sex'].count()
g
```

This gives us a grouped `series`

```
desp  Sex
a     f      2
      m      2
b     f      2
      m      3
c     f      3
      m      1
Name: Sex, dtype: int64
```

Now What i tried is to convert this series to a dataframe using:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'count' : df.groupby( [ "desp", "Sex"] ).size()}).reset_index()
```

Which gives:

```
 desp Sex count
0   a   f   2
1   a   m   2
2   b   f   2
3   b   m   3
4   c   f   3
5   c   m   1
```

Now I created a boolean mask by:

`mask= a.groupby(['desp'])['count'].transform(max)== a['count']`

And this mask will provide you the desired result:

`>>a[mask]`

```
  desp Sex count
0   a   f   2
1   a   m   2
3   b   m   3
4   c   f   3
```